# Angularjs: When does ng-repeat create new elements?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, directive

I understand that ng-repeat is a 'directive', and usually directives have two phases: 'pre' (drilling down into dom) and 'post' (coming back up).

In which of these phases does ng-repeat create the new elements (clones)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the PostLink phase, the template is linked to the Scope and the View is Updated, until then, there are no alterations to the html.

Reference: http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/28/compile-pre-and-post-linking-in-angularjs.aspx